# Diffuse Map to Mesh

Tags: modeling

I have a photogrammed object, the diffuse is pretty good but the mesh isn't that great. I know that I could influence the mesh using a displacement map, but unfortunately I don't have one. Is it possible to somehow transfer the details of the diffuse to the model? The goal is to get more details for 3D printing.
Thx!

[image: Mesh and Texture]

Comment: Hello, use a Displace modifier with the wanted texture and apply the modifier?